# Printing list item in python

Tags: python, list, printing

I have a list of item as follows:

```
language = ["python", "C", "C++", "Java"]
```

I want to print a list item as follows:

```
w[0] = "Pyhon"
w[1] = "C"
W[2] = "C++"
```

I have tried as follow:

```
for id, elem in enumerate(language):
    if elem is not None:
        print("w['id']=",elem)
```

However it is not working as per my requirement.

Comment: "w['id']="  is a hard coded string.  You need print ('w[{0}]="{1}"'.format(id,elem)). Here is the documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 6):

When you print - `print("w['id']=",elem)` - Python would not automatically substitute the `id` inside the string, you would need to format the string correctly so that `id` is printed there.

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for that. Example -

```
for id, elem in enumerate(language):
        if elem is not None:
            print("w[{0}] = {1}".format(id,elem))
```

If you want the elements in the output within quotes, you can use the following `print` function call -

```
print('w[{0}] = "{1}"'.format(id,elem))
```

If you want the first letter capitalized, then -

```
print('w[{0}] = "{1}"'.format(id,elem.capitalize()))
```

Comment: You beat me to it with a slightly different method!

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.

Answer (score 3):

The string in `w['id']=` is being treated as a literal string, that would work in PHP but not python. Use string concatenation like this:

```
language =["python","C","C++","Java"]

for id, elem in enumerate(language):
    if elem is not None:
        print('w[%s] = "%s"' % (id, elem))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for id, elem in enumerate(language):
    if elem:
        print('w[{}]="{}"'.format(id,elem))
```